# What would $P = NP$ tell us about how the polynomial hierarchy relates to $PSPACE$

Tags: complexity-theory

If $P = NP$ it's easy to show by induction that the $PH$ collapses to $P$. But would that have any other implications for the relation between $PSPACE$ and $PH$? We already know that $PH \subseteq PSPACE$ and this continues to hold true in the case of the $PH$ collapsing, but would $P = NP$ imply anything else for the relation(for example, $PSPACE \subseteq PH$?)

Comment: see  https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23745/has-there-been-any-more-progress-on-p-vs-pspace-compared-to-p-vs-np?rq=1

Comment: $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$ would mean $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{PH}$ (because it would cause the polynomial hierarchy to collapse), so I doubt we could conclude $\mathsf{PSPACE} = \mathsf{PH}$.